# Login to a website and open it in web browser

Tags: windows, perl

I am new to perl and i have started with mechanize.

I logged in to a website sucessfully but after that i wanted to open the website in
my browser in windows it just opens the website instead of after logging in.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Win32::API;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use warnings;


my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new(
 autocheck       => 1,
 onerror         => \&Carp::croak,);


my $Email = 'username';
my $Password = 'password';
my $url = 'http://www.gmail.com/';
my $response = $m->get($url);

if (!$response->is_success) {
    die "Login page unreachable $url: ",  $response->status_line, "\n";
}

    $m->submit_form(
        form_number => 1,
        fields      => { 
                       'Username' => $Email,
                       'Password' => $Password, 
                       },
    );

$response = $m->submit();

 $m->add_header(
  "Connection" => "keep-alive",
  "Keep-Alive" => "115");

#$response = $m->click();
if ($response->is_success) {
    print "Login Successful!\n";
} else {
    die "Login failed: ",  $response->status_line, "\n";
}

my $ShellExecute =
  new Win32::API( "shell32", "ShellExecute", [qw(N P P P P N)], 'N' );

my $GetDesktopWindow = 
  new Win32::API( "user32", "GetDesktopWindow", [], 'N' );

my $hWnd = $GetDesktopWindow->Call();


$ShellExecute->Call( $hWnd, 'open', $url, '', '', 1 );
```

Comment: Perhaps you should do some more reading to understand how HTML forms and HTTP GET/POST work. You can't just send `Username` and `Password` fields to Gmail, and expect it to magically work. Their server is expecting specific fields (and more than just those two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argh. You can't just do that.
Do you ever log in to gmail using internet explorer, and then expect it to work in firefox?

...

If you need to log in with your browser, [you should probably just get perl to log in with your browser.](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm)

If you really need to do it with just mechanize, [then you probably need mechanize to store the same cookies your browser uses.](https://metacpan.org/module/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/lib/HTTP/Cookies/MozRepl.pm)